# Send CSV file with db_sendmail - missing records

Tags: sql-server, csv, sql-server-2014, sp-send-dbmail

I am trying to send a csv file with 15000 records via the database mail in SQL Server 2014. The problem is that when I open my email the csv only contains 209 records. I have tried the same thing in SQL Server 2012 and it works as expected - it sends the 15000 records in the csv.

I have tested this on several sql servers with 2014 edition on them, and I have the same issue on all of them. The query breaks off at different points on each sever - for example one of them breaks off at 209 records as i said above, another one at 307. The last record always gets truncated at the same place. The csv attachment size it's about 64 kb - which is well below the 4MB limit i've configured the database Maximum File Size bytes parameter.

What i am doing basically is creating a job that is meant to execute a stored procedure and send the results in a csv in an email. The stored procedure is something like:

```
    select col1, col2, col3 
    from table A1
    where col1 > 1000 order by col1
```

Does anyone have an idea if something changed in the 2014 edition? Or can give me some tips on what to look at next?

Comment: format your question properly?

Comment: Done, sorry it was a bit messy.

Comment: What are the results of the stored proc while executed with the same user that executes it within the SQL Agent job?  Are you getting the 15,000 records?

Comment: When manually executing the stored procedure i get the 15000 records in the resultset. and when executing the stored proc with the same user i get   209 records on one server and 307 on another, both with sql server 2014 on them. While in the same exact conditions on 2012 i get 15000 records both times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer- it's actually a bug on 2014, please see: 
https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/850260/sql-2014-sp-send-dbmail-64kb-query-result-limit